# OrangeHRM internal error ocurred Pls contact system administrator

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I'm new to orangeHRM. Please help me figure out what's wrong with installation. When I try to access using my credentials, it is successful however I'm getting this error msg:

```
 internal error ocurred Pls contact system administrator
```

I tried the solution here: [link](https://hadoanngoc.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/orangehrm-annoying-bugs-internal-error-occurred/)

But it didn't help. Does anyone here know how to print complete error logs? I really need your help.

Thanks.

Comment: any improvements so far? encountered the same error when i tried to implement a new module

Comment: @KarthikNk No. I tried to contact them but they haven't responded yet.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes Internal errors can occur due to various reasons from orangehrm system. Best way to debug the issue is from looking at the log files. Can you post the output of the log file located at `../symfoy/log/orangehrm.log`. If the content is huge, delete the entire content and access the system again till you encounter the issue. Then post the log content here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have install with valid credential and successfully connected to the database,then there would be issue of **CACHE**.
    Clear your cache by opening xampp/wampp shell(command line)

```
  Path to Your orange hrm directory/symfony
```

Write following command in shell to clear the cache

```
php symfony cc
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer as I feel like it's taking me in the right direction but for me I can log in as users because it defaults to pim/viewMyDetails but when I log in as an admin it defaults to pim/viewEmployeeList. This is where my orange has broken since I did a restore from a mysqldump backup.

This didn't fix my issue but it is helping me move forward :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the appropriate php verion

Disable apache module for PHP 7.4.1

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
# Enable the apache module for PHP 5.6
sudo a2enmod php5.6
# Set PHP 5.6 as default for the CLI
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
# Restart apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```